# Further customise a jQueryMobile custom select menu

Tags: jquery-mobile

Does anyone one know of a workaround/hack ;¬) to further customise jQuery custom select menu - i.e. when we've used

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
   $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
});
```

to give us a nice list-item overlay in place of the standard listview page on selecting from a  select menu.

The jQM docs here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/forms/selects/custom.html -  state:

> When it has too many options to show on the device's screen, the
>   framework will automatically create a new "page" populated with a
>   standard listview for the options. This allows us to use the native
>   scrolling included on the device for moving through a long list.

I would like to prevent this and always show the custom overlay; obviously the problem is scrolling the options which are out of view. When my project is switched to landscape thus decreasing the screen height it swithces to the 'old school', clunky listview. I should imagine its down to 'absolute' screen metrics since i can see the custom menu overlay will (just about) fit without reverting to the standard view.

The custom view is a much nicer looking interface, and more intuitive from a UI/UX perspective also.
Anyone know of any tricks to keep this behavior??